# Java - How to break out of for loop by comparing items in an array

Tags: java, loops, break

I need to break out of the for loop if the user enters 99999.The code below wont break the loop and actually calculates 99999 into the average. Thank you in advance for any help.

```
 import java.util.*;
 public class DistanceFromAverage {

 public static void main(String[] args)
 {
  //User input
  Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
  double[] someNum = new double[10];
  double sum = 0;
  double avg;


  for(int x =0; x < someNum.length; x++)
  {  

         if(someNum[x] != 99999)

         {            
         System.out.print("Enter a number >>");
         someNum[x] = input.nextDouble();

         sum = sum + someNum[x];
         }
         else
         {break;}         
  }
  //Figuring the average
  avg = sum/10;

  //Output
   for(int y = 0; y < someNum.length; y++)
   {
     double distance = (someNum[y]-avg);

     System.out.print(someNum[y]);
     System.out.println("   Distance from average >> " + distance);
   }
     System.out.println("Average>> " + avg); 
 }
}
```

Comment: You're checking the current element of x, but you should be checking `x-1`. You could move your `someNum[x] = input.nextDouble();` before the if statement.

Answer (score 0):

Your logic is messed up. You're asking for up to 10 numbers from the user. You've defaulted the array of input numbers to 0. When the user enters 99999, it gets added to the array, then on the next time through the loop, it looks for the next number to compare to 99999 and gets 0.

The entire logic should be rearranged to ask for up to 10 numbers, check the number immediately. If the user enters 99999, then break. Otherwise, put them into an array, keep a count, and average them.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested this, but I've rearranged the logic a little which should set you on the right path.

```
 List<Double> someNum = new ArrayList<Double>();
 do {
     System.out.print("Enter a number >>");
     double thisNum = input.nextDouble();
     if (thisNum == 99999) {
         break;
     }else {
         someNum.add(thisNum);
         sum += thisNum;
     }
 }while (true);

 //Figuring the average
 avg = someNum.size() == 0 ? 0 : sum / someNum.size();
 for(double thisNum : someNum) {
     double distance = (thisNum - avg);
     System.out.print(thisNum);
     System.out.println("   Distance from average >> " + distance);
 }
 //Output
 System.out.println("Average>> " + avg);
```

Answer (score 0):

How about using this as the `for` block:

```
      System.out.print("Enter a number >>");
      double inputValue = input.nextDouble();
      if(inputValue == 99999){
         break;
      }
      someNum[x] = inputValue;
      sum = sum + someNum[x];
```

You won't be able to use `x` outside the loop as is, so use maybe another variable or maybe alter the `for` statement to not declare `x` to be local to the loop.

Using a well-thought-out `while` loop would be better.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an ArrayList and simply specify the loop to increment 10 times for the getInput() method, and then specify the loop to only calculate average based on the .size() of the ArrayList.

This should fix it up for you, and break properly and calculate the average based on numbers input up until the 99999.

```
import java.util.*;

class DistanceFromAverage {

    ArrayList<Double> numbers = new ArrayList<Double>();
    double sum = 0;
    double avg;

    DistanceFromAverage() {
        getInput();
        calculateAverage();
        showOutput();
    }

    void getInput() {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        for (int x = 0; x < 10; x++) {
            System.out.println("Enter a number >>");
            double num = input.nextDouble();
            if (num == 99999) break;
            else {
                numbers.add(num);
                sum += num;
            }
        }
    }

    void calculateAverage() {
        avg = sum / 10;
    }

    void showOutput() {
        for (int x = 0; x < numbers.size(); x++) {
            double distance = (numbers.get(x) - avg);
            System.out.println(numbers.get(x) + " Distance from average >> " + distance);
        }
        System.out.println("Average >> " + avg);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new DistanceFromAverage();
    }
}
```